For JumpTask automation
I want to write a Python code for automatically doing my JumpTask.io tasks because when I try to complete my tasks it redirects me to Google Chrome and shows a blank white screen and the task starts but not completed (PC/mobile both tried). So I would like to make as vanilla as I could.
